# Dedicated Server - what should I be looking for? Virtual private servers?

Tags: hosting

I would like to rent my own dedicated-server which I can run my own game servers on, rather than buying a server specific for one individual application or game.

Any suggestions of what I should be looking for?

Comment: Um, a virtual private server isn't a dedicated server. A dedicated server AFAIK is a physical machine that dedicates all of its resources entirely to you. A virtual private server looks and feels like one, but is actually one of many running on the same hardware, each taking its turn to actually run. Depending on the game, that can add non-trivial amount of lag. It wouldn't matter for a creative Minecraft server, but it might for a competitive TF2 server.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for "Shopping advice or recommendations," both of which are expressly forbidden by the FAQ

Comment: It sounds valid for the "even what I should be looking for" part, but the "places that provide this" are clearly forbidden.

Comment: @badp: It could matter quite considerable for a creative Minecraft server. MC is more demanding than TF2 on server resources, and many VPSes are rather lowly specced. Disk I/O tends to be poor on VPSes too, which will kill Minecraft performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you have the tools to install the game server you want (programs from the games sites) and you know what operating system it requires, you can opt for any hosting platform like any other website.

Be careful on the banswidth you are allocated and the machine specifications. Depending on the number of player you intend to host games for, it may require a certain amount of power.

You can also have a machine of yours in a datacenter if you have enough money and wish to invest in that.

Comment: Don't forget to consider bottlenecks, such as disk IO, RAM, processor, network, etc. I wouldn't host a disk IO-intensive game on a cloud server since they have very limited IO.