# CS GO Server on VPN

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I was told that you can put a server (csgo) on vpn so it would run 24/7? Is this the case or not, and if it is, do i have to get windows server 2012 (because i heard it's the best one)? Thanks

Comment: You do know that steam disapproves of using vpns

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25084/dedicated-server-what-should-i-be-looking-for-virtual-private-servers?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were probably told incorrectly. VPN is a virtual *network* constructed from encrypted tunnels. A *VPS* (virtual private *server*) is more likely what you're looking for. The operating system can be Windows Server 2012, but it can be another version of Windows or even Linux.

[Valve's guide on running a dedicated server](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Dedicated_Servers).